# Cannot iterate over null (null)

Tags: apex, cicd

I am trying to create CI/CD process in GitLab based on trailhead. I reuse snippets of code from trailhead `$ PACKAGE_VERSION_JSON="$(eval sfdx force:package:version:list --concise --released --packages $PACKAGE_NAME --json | jq '.result | sort_by(-.MajorVersion, -.MinorVersion, -.PatchVersion, -.BuildNumber) | .[0] // ""')"` and catch error `jq: error (at <stdin>:9): Cannot iterate over null (null)` . Maybe someone will have ideas on how to get around this error. Thanks in advance!

`(https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/projects/automate-cicd-with-gitlab/package-your-app-and-automate-cicd)`

Comment: The error from `jq` tells you that the `force:package:version:list` didn't output any data to iterate over. I would run the list command as written in the `eval` and see what it produces and start from there.

Comment: Please remove --released (if no pckg has been released then it might cause an issue)